# Изменение OBJECT

Tags: html

Есть исходный код:

> `<OBJECT name=subject data="File1.htm">`
> `<INPUT type=button value=1>`
> `<INPUT type=button value=2>`
> `<INPUT type=button value=3>`

При нажатии на кнопку 2 переменная data в OBJECT должна меняться на "File2.htm", а при нажатии на кнопку 3, должно стать "File3.htm". Т.е. при нажатии на кнопку менялся адрес отображаемого файла. Как это можно сделать с помощью Javascript? Короче, это как с картинкой, когда на неё курсор наводишь, она меняется на другую. Так же и тут, при нажатии на кнопку, менялся файл OBJECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fun(a)
{
  var par=a.value;
  document.getElementById('file').setAttribute("data","File"+a+".htm");
}
</head>
<body>
...
<object name="subject" data="File1.htm" id="file">
...
<input type="button" id="but2" value="2" onClick="fun(this)">
```

И так на каждую кнопку.

Comment: Стоп. У меня почему-то не работает. Не знаю, на орфографию я проверил, все ID сходятся. Но вот не работает. Я нажимаю на кнопку, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, что у вас выводиться в консоли отладки.
Ctrl+Shift+I -> Console

Comment: Всё, вопросов нет. Решил проблему. Была ошибка в том, что я, когда переименовывал ID объектов, поставил называние функции 1(), а в консоли отладки было написано, что цифра не поддерживается. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ;)